# Event Bubbling with OOP

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the ID of the clicked element using a bubbling event.

```
  const _elem = new WeakMap();

  class GetItem {
    constructor(e) {
      _elem.set(this, e);
    }

    eventBubblingTest() {
      const targetElement = _elem.get(this).target;
      return targetElement.parentNode.id;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const clickedID = new GetItem(event);
    alert(clickedID);
  });
```

Currently I'm getting `[object Object]` as the output. My question is **WHY** am I not getting the ID of the clicked child elelemt?

Also is there a simpler way to write the click EventListener?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q3abtw4/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your current code you are alerting the whole class *(You just create a new instance of the `GetItem` and then trying to alert it)*. Instead of this, if you want to get the `parentNode`, `id` property you need to invoke the responsible function for it. So your code should be like this:

```js
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const clickedID = new GetItem(event);
  alert(clickedID.eventBubblingTest());
});
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
const _elem = new WeakMap();
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

class GetItem {
  constructor(e) {
    _elem.set(this, e);
  }

  eventBubblingTest() {
    const targetElement = _elem.get(this).target;
    return targetElement.parentNode.id;
  }
}

parent.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const clickedID = new GetItem(event);
  console.log(clickedID.eventBubblingTest());
});
```

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.product {
  min-width: 20%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}

img {
  max-width: 75%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div class="product" id="col1">
    <img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/7up-13-logo-png-transparent.png" />
    <p> Items 1 </p>
    <button id="buyItem1"> Buy </button>
  </div>

  <div class="product" id="col2">
    <img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/7up-13-logo-png-transparent.png" />
    <p> Items 2 </p>
    <button id="buyItem2"> Buy </button>
  </div>

  <div class="product" id="col3">
    <img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/7up-13-logo-png-transparent.png" />
    <p id="sas"> Items 3 </p>
    <button id="buyItem3"> Buy </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Fergoso Well, since you are passing the event interface into the constructor and use it for further purposes, you can't move it outside the event listener. Unless you change the current structure of your class.